# software-properties-gtk crashes on Ubuntu 16.04 startup

Tags: apt, python, update-manager, gtk

It's about a couple of days that the Software Updater won't alert me for updates. This morning I found out that `software-properties-gtk` crashes repeatedly on system startup and if I try to launch it from the terminal it ends up with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 37, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.gtk.SoftwarePropertiesGtk import SoftwarePropertiesGtk
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 54, in <module>
    from UbuntuDrivers import detect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py", line 21, in <module>
    system_architecture = apt.apt_pkg.get_architectures()[0]
AttributeError: module 'apt' has no attribute 'apt_pkg'
```

A similar behavior for the `update-manager`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 38, in <module>
    from UpdateManager.UpdateManager import UpdateManager
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .UpdatesAvailable import UpdatesAvailable
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdatesAvailable.py", line 61, in <module>
    from DistUpgrade.DistUpgradeCache import NotEnoughFreeSpaceError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 109, in <module>
    class MyCache(apt.Cache):
AttributeError: module 'apt' has no attribute 'Cache'
```

So the problem seems to be related to the python `apt` modules. Nonetheless with either `Python 2.7.12` or `Python 3.5.2` launched from the terminal, I can execute those commands without any problem, e.g.:

```
>>> import apt
>>> apt.apt_pkg.get_architectures()[0]
'amd64'
```

I have also tried to reinstall several `apt`/`python` related linux packages together with `software-properties-gtk` and `update-manager`. However, with no luck.

The list of (maybe) all the packages I've reinstalled:

```
apt apt-utils aptdaemon aptdaemon-data update-manager update-manager-core software-properties-gtk dbus python-pkg-resources python3-pkg-resources python-apt python3-apt python-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon python-apt-common python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0
```

Fortunately the problem affects only the graphical interfaces, i.e. I can upgrade, install or remove ubuntu packages from the terminal through `apt`, `apt-get`, `aptitude`, ... Anyway, it's a bit annoying.

**Update:**
I've also tried (with no luck) to reinstall all the `python3` packages previously installed:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader libpython3-stdlib libpython3.5 libpython3.5-minimal libpython3.5-stdlib python3 python3-apport python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat python3-blinker python3-brlapi python3-bs4 python3-cairo python3-catkin-pkg-modules python3-cffi-backend python3-chardet python3-checkbox-support python3-commandnotfound python3-cryptography python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-dateutil python3-dbus python3-dbus.mainloop.qt python3-debian python3-defer python3-distupgrade python3-docutils python3-empy python3-ewmh python3-feedparser python3-gdbm python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-guacamole python3-html5lib python3-httplib2 python3-idna python3-jinja2 python3-jwt python3-louis python3-lxml python3-mako python3-markupsafe python3-minimal python3-oauthlib python3-padme python3-pexpect python3-pil python3-pkg-resources python3-plainbox python3-problem-report python3-progressbar python3-ptyprocess python3-pyasn1 python3-pyatspi python3-pycurl python3-pygments python3-pyparsing python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-requests python3-roman python3-ros-buildfarm python3-ros-buildfarm-modules python3-rosdistro-modules python3-rospkg-modules python3-setuptools python3-six python3-software-properties python3-speechd python3-systemd python3-uno python3-update-manager python3-urllib3 python3-xdg python3-xkit python3-xlib python3-xlsxwriter python3-yaml python3.5 python3.5-minimal
```

Comment: Hmm, that's an odd one. Can you try to reinstall `python-apt` and `python3-apt` by running `sudo apt install --reinstall python-apt python3-apt`?

Comment: @edwinksl already done and still the same. And it works from terminal so maybe the error is somewhere else but the trigger comes from that, mysteriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. It was related to installing the ROS package `python3-ros-buildfarm` for pre-release testing. It installs a file `/usr/bin/apt.py` which I presume is causing this naming conflict. Removing this package resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Thank you very much Christian! I was going to open an issue, but I've already found yours, great! ;)